# Casting Issue | I am trying to return a similar type

Tags: c#, oop, lambda

I have an ObservableCollection UrlsList. I also have a checkbox in my WPF application which amends items in a list using the IsChecked property. The problem I am having is when I write some lambda expressions to filter the data I want I can't assign it back to UrlsList. It just sets my list to null which then crashes the application. Thanks for your help.

#### ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<URLModel> UrlsList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<URLModel>();

public void CheckBoxOnClick()
{
    if (URLModel.IsChecked)
        UrlsList = UrlsList.Select(url => url.ExistsInDb) as ObservableCollection<URLModel>;
    else
        UrlsList = UrlsList.Select(n => n.ExistsInDb == false) as ObservableCollection<URLModel>;
}
```

[image: Warning Msg]

Comment: `URLModel` is not a bool, its as simple as that, you are trying to push round pegs in square holes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is you are seemingly using `Select` instead of `Where`

The following produces a list an `IEnumerable<bool>`

```
UrlsList.Select(url => url.ExistsInDb)
```

What it seems you want is actually `Where`, Which filters the list

```
UrlsList.Where(url => url.ExistsInDb);
```

---

[Enumerable.Select Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

[Enumerable.Where Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

---

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast an `IEnumerable<T>` back to an `ObservableCollection<T>`. That is bound to fail, because the value returned by a LINQ yuery *is not* an observable collection.

There are a couple of issues with your code:

1. You are using `Enumerable.Select` when you should use `Enumerable.Where`. `Select` projects a list to a list with different values (which is not what you want), while `Where` will filter your list, (which *is* what you want).
2. A LINQ query has to be materialized, for example with `Enumerable.ToList` or `Enumerable.ToArray`. The result of `Where` is a non-materialized `IEnumerable`, whose execution is deferred. Your `ObservableCollection` is a full collection.
3. You can not materialize your LINQ query with a type cast. You have to create the collection yourself.

Considering all of those issues, your code would be:

```
public void CheckBoxOnClick()
{
    if (URLModel.IsChecked)
        UrlsList = new ObservableCollection<URLModel>(UrlsList.Where(url => url.ExistsInDb));
    else
        UrlsList = new ObservableCollection<URLModel>(UrlsList.Where(url => !url.ExistsInDb));
}
```

A more subtle bug in this code is however that when you check and then uncheck your check box, your URL list will be empty, because you first select only the checked items into the list and then select the non-checked items from *that* list. Since you have filtered the list already for the checked items, your second select will yield no result. You will have to store the original list somewhere else and select from there:

```
public void CheckBoxOnClick()
{
    if (URLModel.IsChecked)
        UrlsList = new ObservableCollection<URLModel>(allUrls.Where(url => url.ExistsInDb));
    else
        UrlsList = new ObservableCollection<URLModel>(allUrls.Where(url => !url.ExistsInDb));
}
```

Another issue is, that unless you modify the list somewhere else, you won't need an `ObservableCollection`, since you are reassigning the list when the check box changes. You could either use a simple `List<T>` or array, or - and that is what databinding is actually intended for - you change the content of the databound `ObservableCollection` and then the UI would automatically change with it.

Comment: Thanks Sefe, that is a very descriptive anwswer. Even pointing out the bug that would unfold which I also missed. Now I am getting `url.ExistsInDb=error CS0103: The name 'url' does not exist in the current context`. I really do not understand why this is happen when url is just a temporary variable being used inside the lamba expression?

Comment: Could it be that you are writing `n => !url.ExistsInDb`? You declare the variable to the left of the lambda operator and use it to the right. The name has to match.

Comment: `url => !url.ExistsInDb` this is what I am using. Thats the only way I know how to use lambda expressions :(.

Comment: `if (URLModel.IsChecked)
        UrlsList = new ObservableCollection<URLModel>(UrlsList.Where(url => url.ExistsInDb));` This piece. Saying url does not exist in the current context. my UrlList is initialised within the class.

Comment: That should work. Have you included the System.Linq namespace?

Comment: Yes I have, I can see the code actually runs but it just shows that error during a debug session, thanks a lot for your help Sefe!